# Does it make sense to use Box2D only for collision detection?

Tags: 2d, box2d, collision-detection

I have a simulation I am running where I would like to test for the collision of 2D objects. I am not interested in the physics simulation portion of Box2D but would like to leverage its collision detection features.

My initial thought was to make a bunch of static bodies but after reading the documentation I got the impression they were not included in collision testing and therefore don't make sense.

Is it worthwhile using Box2D to evaluate collision detection in my system, where the position of the elements is driven by a separate system, or does it make more sense to look elsewhere for a collision detection solution? If so, how would I start down that path with Box2D?

Answer (score 4):

Although I have not tried it myself, I guess you could do it by using dynamic bodies, with the world gravity set to zero, and all bodies linear velocity set to zero (so they do not move in world Step call) and then position them using SetTransform. The regular BeginContact/EndContact events should still be sent to your contact listener.

Comment: possibly it's better to use sensors

Comment: Yes, that's true, good point. The only reason you would want normal (non-sensor) fixtures is if you wanted to get the contact normal info which is probably not the case for this type of application because they are not using Box2D for physics in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use Box2D. Box2D has the best collision detection system I've used, compared to Chipmunk and Bullet.

I agree with iforce2d, you should use dynamic bodies with a world whose gravity is set to zero.

Good luck and happy coding.